# Not able print the time elapse for function by using the decorator

Tags: python, time, python-decorators

I created a decorator which calculates the time elapsed for a function by when running the program it gives 0 milliseconds as output for given decorator and in debugging tool it shows the start/ end time is calculated but not able print (end - start) as shown in the code and output.

my code:

```
import time

def time_cal(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start=time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end= time.time()
        print(func.__name__+ ' took ' + str((end-start)*1000) + ' milli seconds')
        return result
    return wrapper

a = (1,2,3,5,3,4,4)

b= [1,2,46,565,464]

c= {'num1': '1','num2' : '2', 'num3' : '3'}
en=[]

@time_cal
def evevn_num(i):
    for i in b:
        if i%2==0:
           en.append(i)
        else:
            print("none are present")
    return print(en)
@time_cal
def list_num(f,s,t):
    print('number one',f)
    print('number two', s)
    print('number three', t)

kwargs = {"t": "Three", "s": "Two", "fs": "One"}

evevn_num(b)
list_num(1,2,3)
```

Output:

```
none are present
none are present
[2, 46, 464]
evevn_num took 0.0 milli seconds
number one 1
number two 2
number three 3
list_num took 0.0 milli seconds

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please help me with a resolution for time calculation as per the code

Comment: Notwithstanding the errors in your code (look at the parameter passed to *even_num()*) the fact is that these functions execute very quickly. In principle, your timer decorator is functionally correct although *time.perf_counter()* is preferred

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and works... could be that your pc is very fast? copy your code in a new empty file and retry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working as intended, it is just the speed to complete the function only takes `.0013666152954102 seconds` to complete.

For testing, add `time.sleep(1)` to your decorator or try with a more complex function.

```
def time_cal(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start=time.time()
        time.sleep(1)
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end= time.time()
        print(func.__name__+ ' took ' + str((end-start)*1000) + ' milli seconds')
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Result:

```
none are present
none are present
even_num took 1009.1550350189209 milli seconds
number one 1 
number two 2 
number three 3 
list_num took 1000.5834102630615 milli seconds
```